# How do I set global Prettier override settings?

Tags: prettier

I want to override some settings for specific files.

For example, instead of creating a `.prettierrc` file at the root of my project, I want to be able to define some global overrides to all files ending with `.sol` in my `settings.json` of VS Code.

```json
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.sol",
      "options": {
        "printWidth": 80,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "useTabs": true,
        "singleQuote": false,
        "bracketSpacing": false,
        "explicitTypes": "never"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add the above to my global settings in VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

### Prettier doesn't support global overrides intentionally

I was trying to do the same thing as you, and realized after researching the issue that it's intentionally unsupported.

From the [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html):

> Prettier intentionally doesn’t support any kind of global configuration. This is to make sure that when a project is copied to another computer, Prettier’s behavior stays the same. Otherwise, Prettier wouldn’t be able to guarantee that everybody in a team gets the same consistent results.

Also see this [response](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1572) in a closed issue on Github:

> Prettier doesn't support global configuration. It's supposed to be configured per project.